# References for distance on the space of automorphisms of probability space

Tags: functional-analysis, ergodic-theory

I'm looking for a good textbooks on ergodic theory, which will help me to learn more about distance between $T,S\in \textrm{Aut}(\mu)$. In particular, I want to read about "common" properties like weak-mixing and zero entropy, or about denseness of conjugacy class of aperiodic automorhism, etc.

Could you please recommend something?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the references by Walter's called Introduction to Ergodic Theory and Ergodic Theory by Petersen: I am pretty much sure it appears in both try to read them all.
There are so many books you might go nuts... (=;